# ODBC connection access denied MySQL

Tags: mysql, odbc, mysql-workbench

I am able to connect to the remote mysql database that is on a different domain that are in the same network, from the sql workbench(using servername.domain.com), but am unable to set up an ODBC connection using the same connection parameters.

I tried to connect using TCP/IP could not succeed. I get "Access denied for user" error, as its trying to connect using the current domain as the host. But the database server is on a different domain.How do we change the domain ?

I was not sure how to use named pipes, any help there would be appreciated.Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you got the domains on your network separated by VLANs? Our organisation has and I've experienced this before. Once the ACLs had been configured connections succeeded.

Comment: @BigChris . Thanks for the reply. The problem is am able to connect using sql workbench with the same connection settings. but not able to set up the ODBC connection.

Comment: Entertain me, and I know the workbench works, but is the user granted access by the full domain you're entering on the MySQL server? Have you tried connecting by IP?

Comment: Yes the user has the access. I tried connecting using IP as well.How do we use named pipes ? ??does that help ??